# Build a jar file with only maven dependency classes

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have 2 projects, project A and project B. Project A is dependent on project B.

**pom.xml** of project A:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nft.dcs</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>

        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-vision-plugin</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Next, I compile my project and it creates a jar with all the dependencies that I don’t need. Created extra folders that do not have to be included in the jar file. I think these dependencies drag along with the dependency from project B.
Using the **dep.xml** file, I indicate which folders you do not need to include in the jar file.

**dep.xml**:

```
<id>with-spec</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <unpackOptions>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>nft/**</exclude>
                <exclude>com/**</exclude>
                <exclude>impl/**</exclude>
                <exclude>javax/**</exclude>
                <exclude>junit/**</exclude>
                <exclude>org/**</exclude>
                <exclude>oshi/**</exclude>
                <exclude>sound/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </unpackOptions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

This method is just awful. Please tell me whether it is possible to add only classes from the dependency to the jar file and not to pull all these other folders.

Comment: Why are you packing `A` as a fat jar in the first place? Since you're using dependency management, you should let Maven pull them through into `B`.

Comment: Did not quite understand what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using scope provided:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nft.dcs</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You should take into account that, as maven documentation states:

> indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a jar with dependencies, probably to run it standalone.

So if A needs B, and B has dependencies on its own, A probably needs those as well to run. It is therefore sensible to pack all the dependencies of B into the runnable jar.

If B has unnecessary dependencies, these should be removed from B.

If B has dependencies, that for some reason are not required when A uses B, you should add a proper exclusion to the dependency in the POM.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But could you more precisely indicate how you can specify the dependency in pom.xml and add it as a jar when building the project.

Comment: You have already added the dependency in your POM. I just wanted to describe to you that _usually_ all dependencies of B _should_ be included in the final jar. If you don't need one or more of those, you should add exclusions to your dependency.

Comment: Now I have all the dependencies from B as separate folders in the jar file of the project A. Can I add the dependency B as a separate jar file in the jar of the project A.